# 1-3 variable htaccess overriding images

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently using the below code for my .htacess file. It is supposed to re-write any http request to https as well as work for 1-3 variables (site.com/cat/subcat/ad).

That part works great, however it is also re-writing my images (i.e "/images/image.png"). How do I correct this code to prevent this from happening and allow my images to show?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  index.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&ad=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteConds only work on the immdiately following rule. If you want the ones checking what was requested is not an existing file or folder to apply to your last two rules as well - then you have to repeat them before each of them. (Or you turn the whole thing around, and use the opposite of these conditions to do a “null rewrite” first, a rule which does no actual rewriting, but stops the current round there.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I duplicated the conditions for each rule, and now it works!